# How to redirect to a specific url

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have the following code:

```
public function numbergrouppost() {

              $groupname            = Input::get('groupname');  
              $no_of_members        = Input::get('no_of_members');

               $create       = Group::create([
               'group_name'          => $groupname,
               'no_of_members'       => $no_of_members, 
               'user_id'             => Auth::id()]);

       return Redirect::route('grouppage');
```

The question is how do I redirect to the page that contains group_id (primary key) within the url. In other words I want to redirect to a url that looks like this:

'/grouppage/{id}'

I could create a function within my home controller but how would I access the `$groupname` variable(code below)? Or would it be best to query the most recent group created by the user?

```
public function groupname() {

$groupbutton = Group::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('group_name', $groupname)->first();

               return View::make('grouppage');
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/grouppage/{id}', array( 'as' => 'grouppage', 'uses' => 'HomeController@groupname'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$groupId` is id of the group, you can pass variable on route like this :

```
return Redirect::route('grouppage', ['id' => $groupId]);
```

Then, in your `groupname` function you can retrieve the `id` :

```
public function groupname($id) {
    // get group by id
    $groupbutton = Group::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('id', $id)->first();

    // pass the gruoupbutton to the view
    return View::make('grouppage', ['groupbutton' => $groupbutton]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to your route by passing parameters. For example if your group id is 10, you can try something below.

```
return Redirect::route('grouppage', array(10));
```

in your case group_id can be retrieved using  $create->group_id.

```
return Redirect::route('grouppage', array($create->group_id));
```

Please refer to http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#redirects.

Comment: I can pass the parameter fine but how do i get my url too look like '/grouppage/32' for example

Comment: Actully I am not clear about what you are asking. But going through your code I think what you are trying to do is, 1. Pass data to numbergrouppost method. 2. In that method create a new group. 3. Redirect to newly created group page.

So I thin what you want is to show details about newly created group? If that's the case, your controller method should look like groupname($id), then you can retrieve group by Id, and pass data to the view.

Comment: thanks @uiroshan although it's because I didn't store `$create->group_id` in a variable.